# Resolution resets after every reboot, Screen Resoultion stuck at 1024x768

Tags: xorg, resolution, screen, startup, xrandr

I installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 12.10 but the problem is that it does not recognize my monitor which is LG E1942. The screen resolution is stuck at 1024x768 and the other option is 800x600 but my monitor has the option resolution of 1366x768.

My system configuration is:

- Intel i7-2600k
- Intel Z68DB motherboard
- 8GB RAM
- Intel HD2000 Graphics(No graphics card....)

I have tried using `cvt` and `xrandr` but it changes to default 1024x768 after every reboot.

Also i am not able to find the xorg.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, we have the same hardware except for the monitor (yours is better). Anyway some rare monitors report having lower resolution (at least 1 resolution lower) than the maximum they support. I have a 1920x1080 TV that only works correctly up to 1680x1050.

My guess is to start playing with `xrandr`. For example, assuming your monitor is VGA-0 and the resolution you want is 1366x768, then do the following in a terminal:

`xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1366x768`

`xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60"`

Play using the --addmode and --newmode settings until you get the one you want. Remember to change the refresh rate also. I put 60 here but could be 50, 55 or other ones for the maximum resolution.

Citing the information from [HERE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Xrandr_Graphical_Front_End_GUI) we have this:

### Adding undetected resolutions

```
Due to buggy hardware or drivers, your monitor's correct resolutions may not always be detected. For example, the EDID data block queried from your monitor may be incorrect.

If the mode already exists, but just isn't associated for the particular output, you can add it like this:


  $ xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600
If the mode doesn't yet exist, you'll need to create it first by specifying a modeline:


  $ xrandr --newmode <Mode``Line>
You may create a modeline using the gtf or cvt utility. For example, if you want to add a mode with resolution 800x600 at 60 Hz, you can enter the following command: (The output is shown following.)


  $ cvt 800 600 60
  # 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
  Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
Then copy the information after the word "Modeline" into the xrandr command:


  $ xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
After the mode is entered, it needs to be added to the output using the --addmode command as explained above.
```

There is also a section about **Setting xrandr changes persistently** which can help if the resolution you set does not stay after you reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the display settings you have to un-check 'Mirror Displays' and then select the right resolution. That should solve your problem. Do this setting even if you are using just one monitor.

In case you are using two monitors you should identify which monitor should be your primary one and at what resolutions should each monitor operate.